# how to apply styling to html by typing the css code to codemirror editor in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how to apply styling to html by typing the css code to codemirror editor?
For example, if the html code is `<head> </head>`, what should I do to make the css code, head{ color : red }, typed in codemirror editor to style this html code?

```
mounted(){
  
    this.htmlCode = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor'),{
      lineNumbers: true,  
      theme: 'dracula',
      mode: 'xml',
      autoCloseTags: true,
    })
    this.cssCode = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('editor2'),{
      lineNumbers: true,  
      theme: 'dracula',
      mode: 'css',  
      autoCloseTags: true, 
    })
  };

methods : {
    clickRun(){
        let htmlCode = this.htmlCode.getValue()
        let cssCode = this.cssCode.getValue()
        let previewWindow = document.getElementById('preview').contentWindow.document      
        let cssAdd = previewWindow.head.append("<style type='text/css'>" + cssCode + "</style>")
  
        
        previewWindow.open();
        previewWindow.write(htmlCode + cssAdd);
        previewWindow.close();
      
    },
}
```

i console logged this code

```
console.log(previewWindow.head)
///<head>
///   "<style type='text/css'>h1{color:red;} </style>"
///</head>

console.log(cssCode)
/// h1 {
///  color:red;
/// }

console.log(cssAdd)

/// undefiend
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style some of elements like `cm-editor` , `cm-scroller`, `cm-cursor` etc..  but are much restricted in styling CodeMirror default formating.
Also themes are bit customizable.
*Themes defined with EditorView.theme. That function takes an object whose properties are CSS selectors and whose values are styles, and returns an extension that installs the theme.*

You can visit complete [docs](https://codemirror.net/6/examples/styling/) .